# how to set window size without extending JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

i just started studying gui in java. i am now able to create windows with specific sizes while extending JFrame. however, i came to read posts from here that it is better not to extend JFrame. then i tried to create a window by setting the size in the JPanel instead, but the setSize doesn't seem to work (my code must lack something)

here's my code for my frame

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class MyFrame{
  private JFrame mainFrame;
  private MyPanel mainPanel;

  public MyFrame(){
      mainFrame = new JFrame();
      mainPanel = new MyPanel(50, 50);

      mainFrame.add(mainPanel);
      mainFrame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

and here's my code for my panel

```
import javax.swing.JPanel;
public class MyPanel extends JPanel{
    public MyPanel(int i, int j){
         setSize(i, j);
    }
}
```

i tried adding frame.pack() in my Frame class, because i thought the frame, not having it's size set, is too small for the panel to be seen -i was wrong

what's lacking in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> what's lacking in my code?

A preferred size for the custom component (`Panel`) for starters.  `@Override getPreferredSize()` to return a logical value.

Then `pack()` the frame to ensure it is the smallest size needed to display the panel and any other components.

So, something like this:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Application {

    private JFrame frame;
    private CustomPanel panel;

    public Application() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        // next 2 lines, just a good idea
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        // at 50x50, the title bar on Windows is wider!
        panel = new CustomPanel(200, 200);
        frame.add(panel);
        // make the frame smallest it can be and still show components
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Application();
            }
        };
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(r);
    }
}

class CustomPanel extends JPanel {

    public CustomPanel(int w, int h) {
        setPreferredSize(new java.awt.Dimension(w, h));
    }
}
```

Comment: Note both `Frame` and `Panel` are confusing names for the custom components given the AWT package has both (the same name) components.  Please use more original names for classes, even/especially in short code snippets meant for others to see.  I commonly use the strategy of `WhatTheAppDoesFrame` & `HowThisComponentGroupCanBeDescribedPanel` ..

Comment: Good on you for being so quick to get it!  :)  See also my (mostly redundant) edit.  ;)